# While running an Ansible-playbook on a Vagrant machine, some important tasks are skipped, but why?

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

This is a portion from an Ansible playbook that I wrote.

```
- name: Check OS Version
  fail:
    msg: "{{ ansible_distribution  }} {{ ansible_distribution_version }} is not compatible with this role"
  when: ansible_distribution != 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release != 'trusty'
```

I'm running the playbook on a Vagrant machine which is ubuntu/trusty and yet the playbook skips the relevant task:

```
# ansible-playbook /tmp/project/deploy/main.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [Deploy] ******************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [install-docker : Check OS Version] ***************************************
skipping: [localhost]

# lsb_release -a:
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

What could be the reason for the skip?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm running the playbook on a Vagrant machine which is ubuntu/trusty and yet the playbook skips the relevant task:
>
> ```
> when: ansible_distribution != 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release != 'trusty'
> ```

It's not really a "skipped task". The task itself is executed, the condition in `when` is evaluated and based on this result: the **execution of** the specified **module** (`fail` in your case) is **skipped**.

The behaviour seems to perfectly match your intention.

The task will execute only if the first condition is true and the second condition is true (simplifying `when: true and true`).

As the machine is ubuntu/trusty:

- `ansible_distribution` is equal to `Ubuntu`, so the first condition (`!=` "not equal to") is false
- `ansible_distribution_release` is equal to `trusty`, so the second condition (`!=` "not equal to") is false

In this case, both conditions are false (`when: false and false`), the whole expression (`when: false`) is also false, so the task skips.

---

If you wanted the task to fail (which is the purpose of the `fail` module) on ubuntu/trusty, you need to change the condition to:

```
when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' and ansible_distribution_release == 'trusty'
```

Comment: I want it to continue to the rest of the tasks only if the machine is ubuntu trusty

Comment: That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Ok i'll check it soon

Comment: To put it another way, when Ansible says "skipped", it means it evaluated the when statement and let that host keep going. If you run the playbook against a host with a different distro, you should see the when statement come out as "true" and the host fail and say "not compatible", like you expect.